# Resolving Render Blocking CSS issue in Dynamic Serving Website

Tags: css, render-blocking

"[www.couponraja.in](https://www.couponraja.in/)" has different pages for mobile and desktop version with same domain name. Due to this I am unable to set the critical path CSS.
How can resolve render blocking CSS issue in my dynamically serving website.

Regards
LadyBug

Comment: Have no idea....but if you post some code, that shows us what you have, and how you want, we might be able to help

Comment: Sorry i cannot share the code as such. But, as we have same urls for both desktop and mobile versions, how we will create first fold css for mobile version of site?

Comment: Well, then not so much we can do, can we...